# How to track app installations from a custom campaign url in iOS

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

I've hired an influencer to promote my Flutter app. I've created a URL link to my app, so I can track the app installations from this influencer's campaign in Google Analytics using the respective UTM builder.

When it comes to Android, everything worked fine by adding some code to the manifest and a dependency to the build.gradle. However, when it comes to iOS, I'm a little confused, and I don't really know what to do.

I've found that I have to ask for permission through App Tracking Transparency. What else should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

We recently faced the same problem. Since we don't want to bother the user with accepting the NSTrackingUsageDescription Permission (since most of the time they deniy it anyways) we took another approach using Apple's in house [campaigns tracking](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/view-app-analytics/manage-campaigns/). You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/view-app-analytics/manage-campaigns/) and see the specific data directly from within AppStoreConnect.

Furthermore we also tried to track everything with AppsFlyer - but we had no success so fare since i guess for ios14+ NSTrackingUsageDescription is reuiqred :(

Will keep this answer updated in the future in case we find a proper solution.